# Including Arduino library in a Makefile for Due

Tags: wifi, arduino-due, makefile, arduino-makefile

I'm currently using a Makefile for the Arduino Due I've found on [Github](https://github.com/jessicacarneiro/arduino-due-makefile/blob/master/Makefile) (with some modifications). It's useful to me cause it allows me to add a [static library](https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic) for cryptographic functions I need and I can't do it using the IDE. Now I need to include the [WiFi library from Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi) but I don't know how. I've tried to put the path to the source (/usr/share/arduino/libraries/WiFi/src) but it gives me warnings saying that some classes are undefined. Does anyone know how to include that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a library isn't as simple as just adding an include path.

You also have to identify each and every source file (or use wildcards as are used for the various sections of the core) and compile them into object files. It is then quite convenient to archive those into a library (.a) file which you can then link your sketch against (if you don't archive you will have to link all the objects files with your sketch in the linking phase).